# networkstream always empty!

Tags: c#, networking

hey I'm writing on an Server-Client program
but when my client sends something, it never reaches my server!

I'm sending like this:

```
    public void Send(string s)  
    {  
        char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();  
        byte[] bytes = chars.CharToByte();  
        nstream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);  
        nstream.Flush();  
    }
```

and Receiving in a background thread like this

```
    void CheckIncoming(object dd)
    {
        RecievedDelegate d = (RecievedDelegate)dd;
        try
        {

            while (true)
            {
                List<byte> bytelist = new List<byte>();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                int ssss;
                ssss = nstream.ReadByte();
                if (ssss > 1)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                }
                if (bytelist.Count != 0)
                {
                    d.Invoke(bytelist.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MSGBOX("ERROR:\n" + exp.Message);
        }
    }
```

the ssss int is never > 1
whats happening here???

Comment: I would have to guess that there is some latent buffering going on. If you call `nstream.Close()` does it get sent *then*? Also, you should check `>= 0` - as 0 and 1 are valid bytes. `ReadByte` returns negative if no data available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NetworkStream.Flush()` actually has no effect:

> The Flush method implements the Stream..::.Flush method; however, because NetworkStream  is not buffered, it has no affect [sic] on network streams. Calling the Flush method does not throw an exception

How much data is being sent?
If you don't send enough data it may remain buffered at the network level, until you close the stream or write more data.

See the [`TcpClient.NoDelay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.nodelay.aspx) property for a way to disable this, if you are only going to be sending small chunks of data and require low latency.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the check of the return value to `if (ssss >= 0)`.

ReadByte returns a value greater or equal 0 if it succeeds to read a byte ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readbyte.aspx)).

To elaborate on Marc's comment: How is nstream created? Maybe there is an underlying class that does not flush.

Comment: Or even `>= 0` (as per my comment)

Answer (score 0):

well, Im creating a TcpClient, and use GetStream(); to get the NetworkStream

Comment: I see you're new to this site. Stackoverflow does not have a discussion structure like most forums. Instead of posting an answer, try to edit the question, or add a comment directly on another user's answer. It's a bit confusing at first, I made the same mistake myself ;)

Comment: About your actual answer: I see, that should be ok. No clue then. :(